# Angularjs setInterval and server load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm designing an app with Ionicframework (phonegap with angularjs layer) which will be connected to a server/db. Users will be able to send message or notification to others users.

Do you think I can create a listener with setInterval (every X seconds) on REST url to check if user has a message ? This application may concern thousands of users. Even if my server will be on cloud architecture with Scala/No-sql technologies, I'm worried about server load.

What do you suggest me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do some research on Push Notifications for mobile devices.

Comment: server load would be just the same as if you did this on a website (some ajax messages refresher), which is quite common solution.

Comment: I already have made search on Push (ex WooshPush etc.), but I don't think it's the solution for frequently message sent.

Ok then I will implement this solution. Keep It Simple Stupid :) Thanks for the confirmation